# Hiding the Global Address Book from a User in Office365

Tags: office365

I have had a weird question asked by a user I provide IT support for, and my gut is telling me it can not be done, but I wanted to be thorough.

Basically, they have set up external user with an internal Office365 account. They want the global address book hidden, so that this user can not view the global address book.

I've been looking around, online, quite a bit; but as one might suspect, all I get are articles concerning hiding that user from others inside the global address book. Senior colleagues are also not aware of this being doable, but can not say for sure.

I suspect people may question why this is being done; long story short, access has been given to provide certain functionalities. It *should* be done another way, but they insist on this way, and the customer is always right.

I'm quite sure this can't be done, but I need something more concrete than 'it is a generic feature, why would they put the effort in to letting you remove it'.

Comment: Address Book Policies: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/address-books/address-book-policies/address-book-policies These allow you to adjust the view members have of the GAL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, with the information we were able to collect, we were able to confidently establish that *no*, this can not be done.